# Is there an AS3 library for determining the beats per minute (bpm) of most mp3 music files?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, mp3

I saw [this](http://blog.jactionscripters.com/2009/05/27/beattimer/) linked to another question on here regarding BPM detection but the site seems to be down now. Can anyone help me out? My question is on the title of this post.

Comment: You know, not all music maintains the same tempo or time signature throughout...  And some music explicitly aims to shatter that concept.  There is music out that that will vex even a seasoned musician.  So don't go asking for a silver bullet that will handle *anything*!

Comment: Well not really looking for a *silver bullet* of sorts. Just want something that can handle most of the songs with a constant beat. Also edited the title so it doesn't sound too explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Check these library:

[SoundTouch](https://github.com/also/soundtouch-as3)

[AS3-audio](https://github.com/singuerinc/as3-audio)